# Apache Airflow Dag not Listing

Tags: python, airflow

I am unable to list the dag which i have created newely.Getting Import Error.Kindly help me to solve below error

```
:/$ airflow list_dags
[2019-12-27 21:07:50,125] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2019-12-27 21:07:50,127] {dagbag.py:403} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/muniaraj/airflow/dags
[2019-12-27 21:07:50,134] {dagbag.py:246} ERROR - Failed to import: /home/muniaraj/airflow/dags/myfirstjob.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/models/dagbag.py", line 243, in process_file
    m = imp.load_source(mod_name, filepath)
  File "/home/muniaraj/airflow/dags/myfirstjob.py", line 1
    Code that goes along with the Airflow tutorial located at:
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Sorry above error corrected but dag is not listing

Comment: Please share the logs , it clearly is a compile issue

Comment: Now Compiler issue solved.but it not listing.   please let me which log u have required.also let me know how to change airflow python 2.7 version to 3.7

Comment: airflow list_dags
[2019-12-28 13:10:22,133] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2019-12-28 13:10:22,140] {dagbag.py:403} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/muniaraj/airflow/dags


-------------------------------------------------------------------
DAGS
-------------------------------------------------------------------
tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Can you please tell me where have you placed your `dag_file.py`? 
Your dag file should be under `airflow-dir/dags`.
Here, `airflow-dir` is the folder you have specified against your environment variable `AIRFLOW_HOME`.
Also, make sure the owner of your dag is the user under which your dag's folder exists, for example, if it resides somewhere under `/home/username/`, the `owner` in `default_args` of your dag definition should be `username`.
Visit the [FAQs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/faq.html) for more such points.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking that maybe that airflow user might not have the appropriate rights to access: /home/muniaraj/airflow/dags if you make a `chown airflow:airflow -R $AIRFLOW_HOME` will solve the issue if it is the case.